# Zoom in/out a table in Titanium

Tags: ios, uitableview, titanium-mobile, pinchzoom

I would like to use pinch gestures to zoom in/out a table in a window.

The table uses a pull-down-to-refresh feature, and hence putting it in a ScrollView intercepts events and adds to the troubles i.e., the pull-down-to-refresh disappears and the Scrollview keeps bouncing.

I would appreciate any suggestion/code snippet to get me started in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: From a UX perspective this just sounds like a really bad idea. I can't think of an instance that zooming out of a tableview is useful.

Comment: Still.. its a requirement and its not restricted by apple i think :) Any Ideas?